# Is touch-chart 1.0  compatible with sencha touch 2.0?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

I need sencha-touch-chart with sencha-touch 2.0. Are they compatible to work together or not?
If not, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

By now you can try Sencha Touch Charts 2.0 Beta

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185725-Sencha-Touch-Charts-2.0-Beta-Now-Available

Comment: I try with sencha touch chart 2.0 beta but it did not give me proper out put.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Sencha Touch Charts is only available for Sencha Touch 1.0 at this time. The core team said that they were working hard to finalize Touch Charts for Sencha Touch 2.0. Hope it will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

No,
but Sencha Touch Chart 2 in beta is available.